# How to merge some commits from Git into SVN?

Tags: git, svn, merge, commit

I have got a git repository, which contains two parts of source code from two svn repositories. The problem is, these three repositories are being maintained at the same time during this short period. Some new features were added to the git repository, while bug fixes were required by all of them.
Now I need to merge some of the commits(some bug fixes) from the git repository back into those two svn repositories, so what is the best practise, anyone could help?

Answer (score 0):

You can try and follow "[git-svn with multiple svn repositories](https://www.redlab.be/blog/2012/git-svn-with-multiple-svn-repositories/)", using a `.git/config` declaring both svn repos:

```
[svn-remote "svn"]
url = http://my.repo.example.org/trunk
fetch = :refs/remotes/git-svn
[svn-remote "othersvn"]
url = https://my.newrepo.example.org/trunk
fetch = :refs/remotes/visualsvn
```

Then:

```
git svn fetch --all
git checkout svn -b localsvn
git checkout othersvn -b localothersvn
```

You can then merge your git commits to those branches (one branch at a time), and from each branch do a `git svn dcommit`.